# error when using ternary operator in formatting string (aka interpolated string)

Tags: c#, compiler-errors

I've written a simple program for finding the smallest permutation of a `string` which is lexicographically larger than the current one. But, the compiler emits the error

> `ERROR CS1003 Syntax error, ':' expected* ".`

I use VS 2015 (update 3) and whenever I compile this program (which seems to be grammatically true), I encounter the aforementioned error.

Does this program have any error in syntax?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const string a = "ABCDEFG";
        //var u = FFG(a);
        //var t = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        //for (int i = 0; i < t; i++)
        //{
        //    Console.WriteLine(FFG(Console.ReadLine()));
        //}
        string u2 = a;
        string u = a;
        do
        {
            //***The follownig line meets Error***
            Console.WriteLine(u + $"{String.Compare(u, u2) > 0 ? true:false}");

        } while ((u = FFG(u)) != "no answer");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    static string FFG(string ss)
    {
        var s = ss.ToCharArray();
        int i = s.Length - 1;
        while (i >= 1 && s[i] <= s[(i--) - 1])
        { }
        if (i == 0 && s[0] >= s[1])
            return "no answer";
        int j = s.Length - 1;
        while (s[i] >= s[(j--)])
        { }
        j++;
        swap(s, i, j);
        int t = i + 1, tt = s.Length - 1;
        if (j - i >= 2)
            while (t < tt)
            {
                //if (t == j)
                //    t++;
                //if (tt == j)
                //    tt--;
                swap(s, t, tt);
                t++; tt--;
            }
        return new string(s);
    }
    static void swap<T>(T[] array, int i, int j)
    {
        T k = array[i];
        array[i] = array[j]; array[j] = k;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a compiler bug. The problem is the interpolated string format you have:

```
$"{String.Compare(u, u2) > 0 ? true:false}"
```

Conditional expressions are required to be surrounded by parentheses because of the `:` within. Normally, the `:` is followed by a formatting expression, which in this case there is none.

Try using this instead:

```
$"{(String.Compare(u, u2) > 0 ? true:false)}"
```

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961160.aspx) (emphasis mine):

> You do not need to quote the quotation characters within the contained interpolation expressions because interpolated string expressions start with $, and the compiler scans the contained interpolation expressions as balanced text until it finds a comma, colon, or close curly brace. **For the same reasons, the last example uses parentheses to allow the conditional expression (p.Age == 1 ? "" : "s") to be inside the interpolation expression without the colon starting a format specification.**

For what it's worth, in my opinion, using an interpolated string here is unnecessary. The result of your string comparison could be useful for debugging, so I would move that out of the string. Additionally, `Console.WriteLine` already is overloaded to accept a format string and tokens, so I would change your console output logic to:

```
do 
{
    var comparisonResult = string.Compare(u, u2) > 0;
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", u, comparisonResult);
} ...
```

You can `.ToLower()` as well if you really care about the casing.

Comment: +1 for the gentle answer to a classic 'it must be a compiler bug' question. It would have been easy to be snarky as well as correct and thorough. Instead you were kind. Good job!

Comment: Yes, there are much more options to choose such as one you mentioned (and even more brief ones) ; but what amazed me was "why this particular form of Interpolated Strings doesn't work ?" , which you concisely stopped my amazement ! Thanks

Comment: Funnily enough, you have to think like a compiler to know why this wasn't a compiler bug :) Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

I think Cᴏʀʏ already answered your question. But in case want to you a different one.

Try `String.Format`:

`Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}", u, String.Compare(u, u2) > 0 ? true : false);`

Hope it helps!

Comment: Oh, didn't know that. Thanks!